# Is it possible to clean the APT cache from the command line?

Tags: command-line, apt-cache

I ask because Ubuntu Tweak's Janitor is frozen due to the sheer number of packages in the cache that accumulated during the upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

`sudo apt-get clean` will do what you want, though it does seem odd that it would freeze based on the amount of packages in the cache.

Comment: OP has been having quite a few other issues as well..

Comment: Just happened to me on 14.04. Ubuntu Tweaks frozen on package 2236... oh well. Nice thing having askubuntu around.

Answer (score 3):

While I could use the terminal to perform this, I'd prefer the GUI.

In [Synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic), go to *Settings* → *Preferences* → *File* tab. Choose *only delete packages that are no longer available* and you're done.

You can also use Ubuntu Tweak, but it takes much longer to do the job.

An update - I've been using BleachBit for some time and the Superuser version lets delete the apt-cache and a lot more.

Comment: This is a comment stating your preferences, not an answer to the question explicitly asking to clean from the commandline. Please do not abuse answer fields for comments not answering the question.

Comment: My read of the question was that the poser tried to use a buggy GUI to begin with and is looking for alternatives, the object being clearing the apt-cache. This is not 'abuse'.