# When running apt-get update I receive checksum errors

Tags: apt

When running `apt-get update` I receive checksum errors on some of the sources packages. I also note that `apt-get clean` cannot resolve my local host name.

Please assist.

Comment: Try this following command may solve your issue $ **sudo sed -i 's/[a-z][a-z].archive.ubuntu.com/archive.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list**

Comment: Add the errors in your question. We need to know which repository it was

Comment: I get a hash sum mismatch on http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dist/precise/main/source/Sources and several other

Comment: Please add the complete error in the question by editing it

Comment: I do not have ssh access to the machine. Can't update my packages. No copy and paste. The error is "Failed to fetch...repository... Hash sum mismatch"

Comment: Tried solutions from this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Comment: No. Not my error.

Comment: Maybe this link helps :- http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116641/how-do-you-fix-apt-get-update-hash-sum-mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove the package lists and rebuild them. Sometimes they get corrupted (they are building with deltas) during syncing the mirrors.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

This could occur due to issues with the mirror you are using (in this case us.archive.ubuntu.com) Sometimes these issues are quickly resolved and simply trying again is effective. If not you need to edit your /etc/apt/sources.lst file and replace `us.archive.ubuntu.com` with another up-to-date mirror from [this list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) or perhaps the main server at `archive.ubuntu.com`

then run `sudo apt-get clean` (which has nothing to do with your hostname) to [clean the apt cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285691/is-it-possible-to-clean-the-apt-cache-from-the-command-line)

Then proceed as normal with:

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`